# Elegant Iteratee -> Enumerator "forwarding" in Play

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0, akka, loops

I wanted to write an app in Play! framework 2.2.x as an exercise in asynchronous approach and the `play.api.libs.iterattee` package. What I wanted to do was get a POST request with a large file upload in its body and send it, chunk by chunk, as a download to a separate request.

The "Play for Scala" book and [this example](https://github.com/nraychaudhuri/async-web/blob/master/demo/play/reactive-upload/app/controllers/Application.scala) lead me receiving the file within the request in chunks I can accumulate or iterate over in any `Iteratee` I define in a custom `BodyParser`. When it comes to [serving a chunked response](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream), I need a provide an `Enumerator` to the response - like `Ok.chunked(enumerator)` and it will be served to the client as the Enumerator provides new chunks.

Now that I want to put it all together, I can't seem to find an elegant and reactive way to propagate asynchronously the new data chunks from the uploading client to the downloading. There doesn't seem to be a good way to "forward" data received by an `Iteratee` (in this case in the `BodyParser`) to a new `Enumerator` (in this case the one providing output to the response).

I have come up with two ways of doing that, but neither of them seems good enough for me:

- use `play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent.boradcast` to generate a `Channel` and an `Enumerator` and within my BodyParser push each received chunk to the `Channel`. The `Channels` don't have the property that the `Enumerator`s have - the Enumerator doesn't produce a new value until the `Iteratee` applied over it consumes the old one. 
  If I were to do it this way, if the uploader had a faster internet connection than the downloader, I would have a "swelling" `Channel` using up more and more memory, instead of handling one chunk at a time.
- create a proxy akka `Actor` and send the uploaded file, chunk by chunk to it, only sending the next one after the last one has been consumed by the downloader. But in this case the confirmation of each chunk being sent to the downloader would have to go through the `Actor` proxy so that the uploader `Iteratee` would send another chunk to the proxy. This seems like unnecessary overhead for me.

I guess my question is twofold:

1. Is there a simple way of constructing a "forwarding" `Enumerator` generating the values received by an `Iteratee`?
2. In my use case, what is the correct way of implementing the scenario I have in mind using Play and Scala's asynchronous toolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Concurrent.joined`:

```
val (iteratee, enumerator) = Concurrent.joined[Array[Byte]]
```

Comment: Looks like what I need - I don't know how I missed that when looking at the API. I'll try it and accept the answer once I get it working :)